# Golang pipeline pattern in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I wanted to learn more about Kotlin coroutines and was wondering if mimicking the Go [merge function](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines) example can be done in a more idiomatic way in Kotlin?

As a newbie I can just translate the `merge` function directly into Kotlin as follows:

```kotlin
fun <T> CoroutineScope.merge(vararg channels: ReceiveChannel<T>) : Channel<T> {
    val outgoing = Channel<T>()

    val jobs = channels.map { channel ->
        launch {
            for ( message in channel) {
                outgoing.send(message)
            }
        }
    }

    launch {
        jobs.joinAll()
        println("done merging")
        outgoing.close()
    }

    return outgoing
}
```

This does however feel like I'm writing Go in Kotlin which is probably wrong.

I'd prefer no experimental API's and functions if possible, only code you can show your boss ;-)

Here's an example of it working https://pl.kotl.in/6ErnutS2X

Comment: That actually looks pretty good to me, although I'd return a ReceiveChannel since you're internally handling the producer side of it. I'm not familiar with Go, but maybe it has some similar idioms. Kotlin also has SharedFlow/StateFlow for representing hot sources of data, and you work differently with them than with Channels. There is a prexisting `merge` function for Flows in the core library.

Comment: Thanks! Noted! Will use `ReceiveChannel` for this case. One thing I must say, the ability to just use generics is quite nice. The Go version of this function does almost exactly the same afaik, except I had to mimic `WaitGroups` with `jobs.joinAll` which seems to work in this context. The flows merge code is a beast! Was a little intimidated. :-D Do you think the outgoing channel close can be done in another way ?